# why __dopostback not working in firefox and IE? But working in chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am converting address in latitude and longitude.

Here is my all code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function codeAddress() {
      if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
          var address = $(".Hno").val() + " " + $(".Address").val() + "," + $(".City").val();
          try {
              // Fetch Lattitude and logtittude for Using Google Map
              var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                      console.log(results[0]);
                      var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                      $('[id*=hdnLat]').val(location.lat());
                      $('[id*=hdnLng]').val(location.lng());
                      javascript: __doPostBack('cMiddle1$btnUpdate', '');
                  }
                  else {
                      alert("Please putt the address info correctly");
                  }
              });

              return false;
          }
          catch (err) {
              alert(err);
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

> And Here is link button

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ERegister" OnClientClick="return codeAddress();"></asp:LinkButton>
```

> And onclick event is declared when page is prerender

```
   this.btnUpdate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnUpdate_Click);
```

> I Alert the latitude and longitude just before the __dopostback and alert works fine. But __dopostback is not working .

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` prefix in Javascript code

Comment: i remove it and tried to execute . but still not working . After clicking button   continuously  , alert("Please putt the address info correctly"); this alert fired up

Comment: Anyone please help me out . i am working over it from very much time.

Comment: if you are getting that alert then your condition is false, have you checked the value of `status` ?

Comment: yes sir, i also alert the status and shows "OK" message. Only problem is that __dopostback is not postingback the page. And one thing . I am using this in .ASCX page.

Comment: Can you create a test sample at jsfiddle?

Comment: thanx everybody it is done now....

Comment: @nirmalsingh, how did you fix it? Posting as answer will help the community